# Why does chainlink price feed use 8 as decimal in USD pairs?

Tags: oracles, chainlink, decimals

I am trying to implement Chainlink's price feed in my contract.
I've learned that when using the USD pair, it always uses 8 as the decimal.
I am curious as to why 8 is used instead of 18, is there a special reason for it?

Answer (score 0):

We can check the decimals function for decimals and description function for pairs in the chainlink contract.

Example for ETH/USD, it's 8 decimals:--https://etherscan.io/address/0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419#readContract

For BUSD/ETH,it's 18 decimals:--
https://etherscan.io/address/0x614715d2Af89E6EC99A233818275142cE88d1Cfd#readContract

Comment: Price feeds use 8 decimals when returning fiat values (ex: USD) and 18 when returning token values (ex: ETH)